# How to reuse the .cs file from other projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8, library-project

I have been working on Android app Development and now have switched to windows.

1) I have a scenario where i need to create a child project and library project, we have done this Android as given in the link - http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

How to acheive the same thing in Visual Studio ? for Windows Phone app development.

2) i have to create a class which will have some methods defined with some values,like :

In my base project

```
Class{

public void string appName(){
 return "XYZ"
}

public void int appVersion(){
 return 1;
}

}
```

Now in my child project i should be able to override the above methods and change the implementation and also if i did not give the implementation it should take the default value.

How to acheive this in C# ?

Comment: You should use an abstract class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx
For using a set of objects/classes in different projects you can create a class library that you will then reference in all of your projects.

Comment: classes don't have to be abstract for being overriden

Answer (score 4):

Usually you don't reuse files in C# but reuse classes,

Create your library project and put your base class there :

```
namespace YourLibraryNameSpace
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual void string AppName()
        {
            return "XYZ";
        }

        public virtual void int AppVersion()
        {
             return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

then in your main project add a reference to the library project and add your child class like this:

```
namespace MainProjectNameSpace
{
    using YourLibraryNameSpace;

    public class ChildClass : BaseClass
    {
        public override void string AppName()
        {
            return "ABC";
        }

        public override void int AppVersion()
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
 }
```

And I suggest following C# naming conventions, like pascal casing method names.

Comment: Strictly speaking you can add files into multiple projects as links but your solution is a much much much better approach!

Comment: Can you please wait i will check your approach and let youknow

Comment: and this BaseClass is what project  ? Like they have "Winodws phone app", "winodws class library project" etc

Comment: You can create just a Class Library project.

Comment: @VahidND can you please also help me with images in the same way ?

Answer (score 1):

In C# it works in pretty much the same way. A library project is a dll, so you can create this one first. Then create your main project. In the solution explorer tree you can right-click on the main project and add a reference to the library project.

Regarding overriding implementation, in c# you need to explicitly mark your methods as virtual if you want this behaviour:

```
Class{

public virtual void string appName(){
 return "XYZ"
}

public virtual void int appVersion(){
 return 1;
}

}
```

and then when you override them in your child class, change `virtual` to `override` (needs to be explicitly stated you are overriding, unlike java).

Comment: while creating the project which one do i need to choose from the list  for creating the library project ?

Comment: if possible can you please show me an example, i am totally confused and with the help of your example i can proceed further

Comment: @Goofy, so your question is how to develop a windows phone application? There are various guides on the web to get you started, e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714071(v=vs.105).aspx. If you get stuck, ask a specific question. Good luck!